# Ionic - Status Bar height

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Is there a way in ionic to get the height of the status bar in px ?
I tried using `screen.height - this.platform.height()` but it also gives me the height of the soft bottom bar in android in some phones.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution :

```
var initialHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFunction);
function resizeFunction() {
    console.log('STATUS BAR HEIGHT', document.documentElement.clientHeight - initialHeight);
    window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeFunction);
}
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
```

Ref : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/issues/112#issuecomment-825044394